# Filter MultiSelectList dynamically based on other form elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone help with this? I have a form with a text element and a listbox, where I would like to exclude the id specified in the text element from the MultiSelectList generated list available to the listbox.

`<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Exclude Value" id="ExcludeID" name="ExcludeID" value="@Model.ExcludeIDName" required /`>

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues, new MultiSelectList(Model.ListOfValues, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedValues),
                                    new {  @class = "chosen", data_placeholder="Select Values" })
```

Comment: `<option>` tags generated by `@Html.ListBoxFor` don't have an `id` attribute. The have a `value` attribute and the inner html (display text) as in `<option value="1">Option 1</option>`. Do you want to delete the option by its value or text or the index

Comment: It would be most user friendly to allow id or text in the ExcludeID text element and remove it from the list by either. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes its possible, but you have already accepted an answer that does not work, so not sure if you want a working solution or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in jquery,

```
$("#ExcludeId").blur(function(){
    $("#SelectedValues > option[id="+ $(this).val() +"]").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter it out before creating the MultiSelectList:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedValues,
                 new MultiSelectList(Model.ListOfValues.Where(item => item.ID != Model.ExclueIDName), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedValues),
                 new {  @class = "chosen", data_placeholder="Select Values" })
```